# R: Display side by side a a variable number of ggplots generated within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function DisplayPlot which takes as an input a list of strings (which refers to columns in a dataframe). 
For instance, if list_string = c("string1","string2"), looping on the elements of list_string, I would like to display the two ggplots side-by-side.

So far what I have done in my function is storing the ggplots into a list:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_string){
p = ggplot(data=d, aes(x=d[,1], y=as.numeric(levels(d[,(i+1)]))[d[,(i+1)]], fill=d[,1])) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
      labs(x = Y) + labs(y = paste("CP",list_X[i],"_per_",Y,sep = "")) 
graph[[length(graph) + 1]] <- p }
```

and return:

```
  return(list(graph=graph, along with some other information))
```

The issue is that if I want to use a function like `grid.arrange`, I need to write manually the names of the plots: `grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)` whereas in my case, this number may vary and are stored into a list (format that `grid.arrange` does not like).

Thank you very much in advance for your help,
Clement

Comment: as a side-note, you should never use `[` or `$` inside `aes`

Comment: why should I never use them inside aes?

Comment: Here's an illustration of what can go wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32543753/471093

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. In fact, I've done this because I did not find an other way to do it: in your example, x is known, x is a vector containing the values. In my case (because I looked for maximum scalability...and also because I'm not a pro R programmer!), the name of my columns do not contain values. So to have access to that name I'm using [ . If you see any solution I'll be very happy to use it

Comment: there are several ways to approach this without resorting to `[`; please post a new question with a self-contained minimal example (including mock-up data)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
grid.arrange(grobs = graph)
```

or (historically, there wasn't always a grobs argument),

```
do.call(grid.arrange, graph)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works good. The multiplot() function is also a good solution

Answer (score -2):

I found an answer to my problem.

```
multiplot(plotlist=graph,col=length(list_string))
```

from the Rmisc package

Comment: You should say where you got the `multiplot` function from.  It appears to be in a bunch of different packages, mostly drawn from [this page of the R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/)