# Wrong colour when using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

The `df` consists of two normal variables:`a`,`b`, one colour variable:`c` and one group variable:`d`

```
df<-data.frame(c(1:5,11:15),c(1:10),c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),c(rep('o',5),rep('m',5)))
colnames(df)<-c('a','b','c','d')
```

I want to have `o` and `m` groups in one plot, so I do the following:

```
qplot(a,b,data=df,geom = 'point',color=factor(df$c))+facet_wrap(~d)+scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","orange"))
```

[image]
The colour of the plot result is wrong, according to `df`, group `m` is supposed to have blue and orange points.
Why does this happen? How could I do the right plot?

This question is similar to [Behavior ggplot2 aes() in combination with facet_grid() when passing variable with dollar sign notation to aes()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543340/6670282). My case suggests that never use `$` or `[` in not only `aes()` but also `facet_wrap()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$` notation in `ggplot` aesthetics. Use raw variable names instead:

```
qplot(a,b,data=df,geom='point',color=factor(c)) + 
  facet_wrap(~d) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","orange"))
```

Comment: This really helps, thanks a lot! By the way, how can I locate these two groups in one colume with two row rather than one row with two columes as ploted above?

Comment: That should work: facet_wrap(facets, **nrow = NULL, ncol = NULL**, scales = "fixed", shrink = TRUE, labeller = "label_value", as.table = TRUE, switch = NULL, drop = TRUE, dir = "h")

Comment: Read ?facet_wrap and note the nrow argument.

Comment: When I use `facet_wrap(~d,nrow = 2)`, I got `Error in plyr::eval.quoted(vars, data, emptyenv(), try = TRUE) : 
  envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.`

Comment: @YQ.Wang It works fine for me.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to generate the test dataframe. My fault.