# Lack of basic understanding of facet_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a (probably) easy problem with histograms in ggplot2 when using `facet_wrap` with this sample-table

```
res<-data.frame(c('a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2'),c('b1','b1','b2','b3','b1','b2'),c(1.0,1.5,2.5,4.0,1.0,2.5))
colnames(res)<-c("A","B","C")
```

I would have expected

```
ggplot(res,aes(res$C, fill=res$A))+geom_histogram(binwidth=1)+facet_wrap(~B)
```

to result (amongst other bars) in one bar in the `b3` facet at `C=4`. However, the only bar at `C=4` shows up in the `b2` facet. I think by naive idea of facet_wrap doing for ggplots what a group by would do in SQL does not seem to work. Could anyone give me a hint at what I am doing wrong?

Comment: don't use the $-operator inside of `aes`, just `ggplot(res, aes(C, fill=A)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1) + facet_wrap(~B)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! The reason for the weird behaviour was that values for    different rows were mixed by filtering? Or rather that the association was broken?

Comment: @Snafusmurf `$` breaks the link. You may wish to check out the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/behavior-ggplot2-aes-in-combination-with-facet-grid-when-passing-variable-wi).

Comment: thx a lot @Z.Lin