# How to unstack bars of barplot and display percentage on top of the bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have dataset that has 17  categorical variables. However, I am interested in two variable `name` (Contains 33 different hotel names) and `NPS_Type` ('Promoter and Detractor).

I am using below code to generate barplot, but for some reason the percent calculation seems to be reversed. i.e barplot is displaying percentage of promoter on Detractor bar and vice versa. So, I thought may be unstacking barplot might help. Any suggestion of how to fix this issue?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(few_var5, aes(x='Hotel Name-Long_PL', y = NPS_Type, fill= NPS_Type)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = 0.25)
```

Sample that might be useful:

```
Casino_PL Postal Code_PL Fitness Center_PL Property Longitude_PL Mini-Bar_PL Spa_PL  NPS_Type
105802          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105803          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105805          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105814          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105819          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105848          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105849          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105908          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105917          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105920          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105922          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N Detractor
105930          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105935          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
105961          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N Detractor
105983          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106003          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106007          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106031          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106033          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106040          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106043          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106051          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106058          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106065          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106083          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106104          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106116          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106161          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106180          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106182          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106202          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106206          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N Detractor
106216          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106218          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106253          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106278          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106305          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106326          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106328          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106331          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106359          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106389          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106418          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106434          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106441          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106464          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106468          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106474          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106526          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
106530          N          94523                 Y             -122.0611           N      N  Promoter
134812          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134815          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134820          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134822          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134825          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134826          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134827          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
134829          N          94002                 Y             -122.2710           N      N  Promoter
                                           POV_H Property Latitude_PL Pool-Indoor_PL   State_PL
105802                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105803                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105805                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105814                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105819                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105848                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105849                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105908                                  Business             37.94289              N California
105917                                  Business             37.94289              N California
105920                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105922                                  Business             37.94289              N California
105930                                  Business             37.94289              N California
105935                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105961                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
105983                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106003  Combination of both business and leisure             37.94289              N California
106007                      Prefer not to answer             37.94289              N California
106031                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106033                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106040  Combination of both business and leisure             37.94289              N California
106043                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106051                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106058                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106065                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106083                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106104                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106116                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106161                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106180                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106182                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106202                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106206                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106216                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106218                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106253                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106278                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106305                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106326                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106328                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106331                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106359                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106389                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106418                      Prefer not to answer             37.94289              N California
106434                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106441                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106464                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106468  Combination of both business and leisure             37.94289              N California
106474                                  Business             37.94289              N California
106526                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
106530                                   Leisure             37.94289              N California
134812                                  Business             37.53244              N California
134815                                  Business             37.53244              N California
134820  Combination of both business and leisure             37.53244              N California
134822  Combination of both business and leisure             37.53244              N California
134825                                  Business             37.53244              N California
134826  Combination of both business and leisure             37.53244              N California
134827                                  Business             37.53244              N California
134829                                  Business             37.53244              N California
        LENGTH_OF_STAY_C Condition_Hotel_H          City_PL Pool-Outdoor_PL
105802                 3                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105803                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105805                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105814                 4                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105819                 9                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
105848                 1                 8    Pleasant Hill               Y
105849                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105908                 5                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105917                 4                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105920                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105922                 2                 5    Pleasant Hill               Y
105930                35                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
105935                 3                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
105961                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
105983                 2                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106003                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106007                49                 8    Pleasant Hill               Y
106031                 4                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106033                10                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106040                 5                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106043                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106051                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106058                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106065                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106083                12                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106104                 4                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106116                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106161                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106180                 2                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106182                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106202                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106206                 1                 6    Pleasant Hill               Y
106216                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106218                79                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106253                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106278                 3                 8    Pleasant Hill               Y
106305                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106326                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106328                32                 8    Pleasant Hill               Y
106331                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106359                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106389                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106418                11                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106434                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106441                 3                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106464                 1                 9    Pleasant Hill               Y
106468                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106474                 3                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106526                 1                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
106530                 2                10    Pleasant Hill               Y
134812                 2                10          Belmont               Y
134815                 2                10          Belmont               Y
134820                 6                10          Belmont               Y
134822                 1                10          Belmont               Y
134825                 6                 9          Belmont               Y
134826                 2                 8          Belmont               Y
134827                 7                10          Belmont               Y
134829                11                10          Belmont               Y
                                   Hotel Name-Long_PL Shuttle Service_PL
105802                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105803                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105805                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105814                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105819                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105848                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105849                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105908                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105917                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105920                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105922                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105930                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105935                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105961                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
105983                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106003                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106007                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106031                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106033                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106040                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106043                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106051                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106058                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106065                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106083                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106104                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106116                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106161                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106180                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106182                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106202                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106206                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106216                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106218                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106253                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106278                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106305                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106326                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106328                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106331                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106359                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106389                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106418                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106434                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106441                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106464                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106468                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106474                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106526                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
106530                      HYATT house Pleasant Hill                  Y
134812             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134815             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134820             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134822             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134825             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134826             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134827             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
134829             HYATT house Belmont/Redwood Shores                  Y
```

Thanks in advance for time and effort!

Comment: You might want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combination-wi) and avoid using the dollar operator inside `aes`!

Comment: @aocall I tried removing $ from aes still no luck. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: If you could share your data in a more "friendly" format (ie, something that could be easily loaded into R without manual effort) it would be easier to help. Perhaps `dput` or similar

Comment: @aocall Not sure if this helps dput(few_var5, "temporary_file")
theDataReconstitutedAgain <- dget("temporary_file")
print(theDataReconstitutedAgain)

Comment: please provide your data by copying the output of dput(your_sample_data)

Comment: Replace your data with the output of `dput(few_var5[, names(few_var5) %in% c("Hotel Name-Long_PL", "NPS_Type")])` so that we can build the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Without an easy to use dataset or a graph to exactly understand what you have done wrong, I am having to slightly guess here. Here is a sample data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("One", "Two", "One", "Two"), 6),
             group = c("Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red"))
```

You need to make the labels in `geom_text` stack so that they are stacked for each bar. By adding `position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` it will plot the label in the centre of each bar:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = group, fill= group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat = "count", 
            position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

If you would prefer them not stacked, you need to alter the `geom_bar` and `geom_text` arguments:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y = group, fill= group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat = "count", 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -1)
```

[image]