# ggplot2 box plot analysis along a given factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame containing three factors (Scenarios, Emission Target, and Climate Action Year) against which there are several numeric-valued metrics.

What I am looking for is to create a box plot for a given metric analyzed over the "Scenarios" factor and plotted as a function of "Climate Action Year" factor, faceted as a grid by the factor "Emission Target".

Here is what I tried:

```
a1 <- ggplot(ResDF, aes(ResDF$CAY, ResDF$IncrCost)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + facet_grid(~ResDF$EmRedTgt, scale="free") + theme_minimal()
b1 <- ggplot(ResDF, aes(ResDF$CAY, ResDF$Etot)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + facet_grid(~ResDF$EmRedTgt, scale="free") + theme_minimal()
p <- grid.arrange(a1,b1)
```

Instead of there being 36 box plots, one for each for each climate action year between 2015 and 2050 for each of the emission targets, I see 9 box plots each for each emission target (see attached figure). The data frame I am using can be found here ([data frame csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqsobptu0w2skao/ResDF.csv?dl=0)).

[image: Plot obtained from this code]

As a novice to R, I think I'm missing something obvious here.  It also makes me wonder what dimension the box plot stat is analyzing. Any directions would be most helpful!

Comment: It would help to see the data in `ResDF`. Also, there is no need to use `$` inside `aes()`. Just use _e.g._ `ggplot(ResDF, aes(CAY, IncrCost))`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my initial post with a link to the ResDF csv file.

Comment: I agree with @neilfws. *Never* use `$` inside `aes`, especially not in combination with `facet_grid`/`facet_wrap`. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combination-wi/32543753).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$` is creating the problem. Assuming that `CAY` is already a factor, if you just do this:

```
ggplot(ResDF, aes(CAY, IncrCost)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid(~EmRedTgt, scale = "free") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

the result is this:

[image]