# Plot pairwise scatterplot with condition using facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long data frame like the following:

```
data = data.frame(
  id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), each = 5),
  pt = rep(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), each = 5),
  value = rnorm(35, 10, 1)
)
```

`id` here is the sample ID, while `pt` is the patient ID. Not required information, but may help to understand the purpose. One `pt` has multiple `id`s, as these are replicates.

I want to make a pairwise scatterplot of the replicate samples. This means for a single `pt`, I want all of the combinations of scatterplots for `id`.

The desired output would be a facet grid with scatterplots for `A_1 vs A_2, A_2 vs A_3, A_1 vs A_3, B_4 vs B_5, B_4 vs B_6, B_4 vs B_7, B_5 vs B_6, B_5 vs B_7, B_6 vs B_7`, in the format `pt_id`.

How could this be done? If I were to convert this from long to wide, and then run pairs, I would get all combinations, but I am only interested in combinations from the same `pt` and would like a facet_wrap object.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for but these can give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/q/50520885/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/786542