# How to make scatterplots according to specific requirements of color?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

```
colored = c('red','blue','yellow')
plot(iris$Petal.length,iris$Petal.Width)
```

I was trying to plot iris$Pedal.width and iris$Pedal.length, and I wanted the color to follow the species of the flowers.(there are 3 species 'setosa','versicolor','Virginia')

I create a color vector, and I want all the setosa to be red, all versicolor to be blue and all Virginia to be yellow. how can I use the color vector in plot(iris$Pedal.width,iris$Pedal.length) to achieve this goal?

Comment: Didn't you ask the *same* question about an hour ago? This is a *very* basic plotting question; you can find many tutorials showing you how to do exactly that, using the *same* sample dataset. Please do some research before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `ggplot` solution rather than `plot`?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "red", "versicolor" = "blue", "virginica" = "yellow"))
```

Comment: Never `$`-index variables inside `aes`. Doing so can lead to [unexpected/undesired results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio).

Comment: @MauritsEvers; I missed it while copy+pasting. Thank you for the reminder, just edited.