# One category per faceted box plots

Tags: r, boxplot

I would like one category per faceted box plot. Instead I am currently getting distribution points for all categories in each faceted box.

```
Category   Age
A          31
A          35
A          28
B          34
B          30
B          40
C          22
C          25
C          24

ggplot(DATASET, aes(x = DATASET$Category, y = DATASET$Age)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle('Distribution of Player Age By Category') +
    facet_grid( .~DATASET$Category )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real need for facets here other than aesthetics (see @LAP's answer), but if you insist on using facets you can do

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Age)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle('Distribution of Player Age By Category') +
    facet_wrap(~ Category, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

**More importantly, never use `$` (column indexing) inside `aes`. This can lead to [very unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio), in particular when using facets.**

Answer (score 0):

No need to facet for boxplotting with `ggplot2`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Category   Age
A          31
A          35
A          28
B          34
B          30
B          40
C          22
C          25
C          24", header = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = Age)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle('Distribution of Player Age By Category')
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible for A to be in a facet box, b to be in another facet box and so on?

Comment: See @MauritsEvers answer if you really need the boxes.