# Why does filtering to a sample of a dataset inside ggplot() return an incorrect sample?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, sample

The context is that I have many time series for many `id`s and many `band`s, and I have included a sample of nine `id`s and two `band`s. Here we can see that I can easily plot the time series for all the `id`s:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1011L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L), date = structure(c(1488884400, 1490612474, 1507460497, 1502276146, 1514372627, 1512644789, 1500980863, 1503572707, 1513940711, 1496660730, 1495796861, 1512644789, 1488884400, 1504436115, 1502276146, 1495796118, 1494068453, 1504868786, 1513940711, 1511780307, 1511348810, 1503572707, 1497524848, 1507028336, 1491476744, 1503572707, 1492340161, 1501844755, 1505300762, 1503140790, 1509620381, 1488884400, 1487156167, 1510052273, 1491476744, 1494068453, 1513940711, 1489748810, 1498388749, 1509620381, 1500980120, 1511780307, 1502708860, 1489748810, 1501412778, 1504436115, 1495796861, 1493204748, 1510484382, 1487156167, 1508324436, 1500548201, 1513940711, 1505732183, 1490612474, 1496660730, 1511348810, 1514372627, 1494068453, 1510052273, 1500548201, 1513076347, 1508756553, 1510484382, 1504436858, 1504004193, 1494932749, 1508324436, 1512644789, 1504868786, 1507460497, 1504004193, 1503140790, 1500980120, 1512212632, 1491476744, 1513940711, 1508756553, 1504436115, 1490612474, 1495796861, 1509188631, 1508756553, 1486292805, 1504004193, 1498388749, 1495796861, 1486292805, 1513940711, 1499684790), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), band = c("fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit1", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5", "fit5"), value = c(0.496538754230172, 0.503271496428091, 0.97387311299285, 0.580658673638122, 0.55924511798107, 0.832069876834949, 0.669456383223215, 1.12835570514478, 0.650077806710299, 0.380956367547047, 0.315803532869213, 0.792491389890908, 0.542150595815071, 1.03016500582205, 0.761751198659722, 0.367933240661702, 0.478285303617102, 1.68901870452092, 0.740965064159661, 1.09028738312622, 0.822334909416119, 0.758342181009204, 0.404208383270466, 0.892795714415756, 0.452540219822814, 1.15220190981348, 0.522093412373678, 0.953592910857701, 1.27850667816495, 1.10756222303339, 0.722797148902218, 0.465842402588039, 0.524130056243481, 0.724757971315511, 0.401849347220063, 0.455169211763473, 0.736683498842155, 0.530595901306756, 0.598435246507131, 0.855911625573028, 0.459872179640563, 0.851473466057886, 0.600348304937791, 0.484896112230185, 0.491357621589034, 1.21884821937325, 0.408355867626313, 0.541537217668289, 1.20173675518489, 0.61126928681528, 1.02122136799224, 0.489289990779144, 0.829092258901136, 0.88152853467569, 0.528559966420024, 0.544164467022259, 1.15093592993106, 0.876559089290843, 0.582149928218707, 1.26592404446571, 0.479960992971744, 0.840894959543198, 1.00459298341354, 0.98285777345435, 0.754965044767638, 1.14971147250154, 0.678568628236206, 1.38981008816777, 0.989354634818581, 1.25116433808614, 1.2142398253614, 1.03201975237089, 0.928602154928637, 0.642961745200205, 0.842888403466734, 0.649606669375906, 0.724490820076092, 1.68294181717141, 1.83216850101507, 0.69741924948021, 0.268972923828825, 1.16584414990533, 1.20604228862346, 0.586060027904748, 1.16356144256577, 0.52670838257608, 0.382147314320451, 0.668308513834733, 0.78509264848017, 0.733357618207109)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("id", "band"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:4, 5:9, 10:14, 15:19, 20:24, 25:29, 30:34, 35:39, 40:44, 45:49, 50:54, 55:59, 60:64, 65:69, 70:74, 75:79, 80:84, 85:89), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1004L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1007L, 1007L, 1009L, 1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1013L, 1013L), band = c("fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("id", "band"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:4, 5:9, 10:14, 15:19, 20:24, 25:29, 30:34, 35:39, 40:44, 45:49, 50:54, 55:59, 60:64, 65:69, 70:74, 75:79, 80:84, 85:89), group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(merge_id = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1004L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1007L, 1007L, 1009L, 1009L, 1010L, 1010L, 1011L, 1011L, 1013L, 1013L), band = c("fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5", "fit1", "fit5")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("merge_id", "band"), drop = TRUE)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = band)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

However, this becomes unwieldy and the plots become too small when there are too many `id`, so I want to visually inspect a random subset. I would expect the following to return just three of the `id`s, but instead we get four `id`s and we don't even get all the `band`s for every `id`. I choose seed 1234 here but you get a different result if you keep rerunning with different seeds, with different arrangements of band-id combinations.

```r
set.seed(1234)
ggplot(
  data = df %>% filter(id %in% sample(unique(df$id), 3)), # filtering to subset of 3 ids
  mapping = aes(x = date, y = value, colour = band)
) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

Note that it works if I do the sampling outside of the `ggplot()` call. (This would be the desired result)

```r
set.seed(1234)
some_ids <- sample(unique(df$id), 3) # moved sample() outside of ggplot()
ggplot(
  data = df %>% filter(id %in% some_ids),
  mapping = aes(x = date, y = value, colour = band)
) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

Why is this happening? I cannot see the difference in logic between the two options. It is definitely related to `sample` and not the `unique(df$id)` part, since you can replace that with `c(1001, 1002, 1004, 1005, 1007, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1013)` and still get the problem. I am also cognizant that it may be something to do with my specific data, since I did try making an analogous reprex with a built-in dataset, but I cannot imagine what that would be since this is already a pretty limited subset.

EDIT: for example, I cannot reproduce this error if I use this even more stripped down dataset. I am befuddled because I cannot tell any difference between this dataset and the one in my `dput` except for the actual values.

```r
df2 <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:9, each = 5, times = 2),
  date = rep(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00"), by = "month", length.out = 5), times = 18),
  band = rep(c("b1", "b2"), each = 45),
  value = c(rnorm(45, 0), rnorm(45, 1))
)
```

Comment: When I run your first code block, it seems as if there is an unclosed parenthesis.

Comment: It works for me in a clean session. I just used `styler` to put the `dput` on one line, shouldn't have messed with any parens

Comment: You're right, I saved it to script and it worked fine. Must've been something weird with the console.

Comment: Hopefully this helps someone find the answer as I'm not super familiar with `dplyr`, but if you use a regular data frame index filter, then it works as expected: `ggplot(data = df[df$id %in% sample(unique(df$id), 3), ] #...`

Comment: ^ this does work, though I would still like to know what the point of difference is here!

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543753/6666231) is related, but personally I'd avoid using `$` in functions of `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: The filter expression gets evaluated multiple times, so you should not use a non-deterministic expression.

Not sure if this is good enough for an answer, but if you try to run your example with different seeds, you'll notice that the number of charts changes with each seed. This suggests that the number of ids we are filtering the data frame changes with each seed, suggesting that `sample` is actually called multiple times. We can confirm this by creating a function that takes the place of `sample`:

```
sample_out <- function(data, n) {
  print("running sample_out ")
  return (sample(data, n))
}
```

and then using it in place of `sample`:

```
ggplot(
  data = df %>% filter(id %in% sample_out(unique(df$id), 3)), 
  mapping = aes(x = date, y = value, colour = band)
)
```

you'll see that `sample_out` actually gets called multiple times. In my session, this gets called 18 times with the data above, regardless of seed. Experimenting with different data frame sizes, it seems like `sample` will get called (row_count / 5) times. This implies that `filter` somehow evaluates its argument multiple times. A complete answer would explain why this happens with `filter` but this is where I get a bit lost. I believe that the relevant source is here:

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/tbl-df.r#L55

```
filter.tbl_df <- function(.data, ..., .preserve = TRUE) {
  // elided
  out <- filter_impl(.data, quo)
```

`filter_impl` basically calls a C++ implementation, and I think the key line is:

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/src/filter.cpp#L408

```
template <typename SlicedTibble>
SEXP filter_template(const SlicedTibble& gdf, const NamedQuosure& quo) {
  // elided
  Proxy call_proxy(quo.expr(), gdf, quo.env()) ;
  // elided
  int ngroups = gdf.ngroups() ;    
  // elided    
  for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++, ++git) {
    // elided
    LogicalVector g_test = check_result_lgl_type(call_proxy.get(indices));
    // elided
  }
  // elided
}
```

Note that for each group of the tibble, `call_proxy.get` is executed. I am assuming that we see `sample_out` get called 18 times because there are 18 groups in the corresponding tibble.

Anyway, this could probably be answered quickly and authoritatively by posting to the relevant dplyr community contact. In my adventure learning about dyplr, I was unable to find a warning about this, so it could be that I am missing something. `dplyr`'s documentation discusses that it's evaluation is a little different than may be used to: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

> Most dplyr functions use non-standard evaluation (NSE). This is a catch-all term that means they don’t follow the usual R rules of evaluation. Instead, they capture the expression that you typed and evaluate it in a custom way.

Comment: This makes sense to me - writing a custom function is a smart way of checking! I am confused why I don't seem to get the bad behaviour when I use the even more stripped down dataset at the bottom of the question, though. I'll post to the github when I get a chance to ask, and I'll leave this up for a bit longer else I'll come back to accept. Thanks!