# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data issue is ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, aesthetics

I am trying to plot a line graph in ggplot. But I am geeting this error:

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): y, x, group
```

This graph contains 4 lines. I have one more graph which makes use of same data frame but different two columns. I dont understand why that graph is working properly but this graph is not. I tried all possible answers I found.But nothing is working. Other graph is made using `expkm` and `actualkm` with dates at x axis.

```
pred <- ggplot(data_, aes(x= data_$dates, group=1)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = data_$exp))+
    geom_point(aes(y = data_$facc))+
    geom_point(aes(y = data_$cntrmlg))+
    geom_point(aes(y = data_$top10rem))+
    geom_line(aes(y = data_$exp, color='Expected')) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = data_$facc, color='Actual'))+
    geom_line(aes(y = data_$cntrmlg, color='status'))+
    geom_line(aes(y = data_$top10rem, color='Statusy'))+
    geom_label(aes(y = data_$exp,label = data_$exp,hjust = 0,vjust = -0.2))+
    geom_label(aes(y = data_$facc,label = data_$facc,hjust = 0,vjust = 0.2 ))+
    geom_label(aes(y = data_$cntrmlg,label = data_$cntrmlg,hjust = 0,vjust = -0.2))+
    geom_label(aes(y = data_$top10rem,label = data_$top10rem,hjust = 0,vjust = 0.2 ))+
    labs(title = "Reli")+
    labs(x="Dates")+
    labs(y="")+
    guides(color = guide_legend(title = ""))
```

Sample data :

```
     expkm
    50000
    100000
    112500
    137500
    150000
    162500
    187500
    187500
    187500

   actualkm dates  exp      facc        cntrmlg     top10rem
    26013   Dec-17  32660   26013       50000       26013
    56796   Jan-18  46188   13802       75000       41405
    52689   Feb-18  56569   19357       87500       45166
    64657   Mar-18  65320   25019       100000      50039
    79445   Apr-18  73030   21508       91667       46600
    92647   May-18  80000   19592       101786      53178
    121944  Jun-18  86410   16473       75000       41183
    125909  Jul-18  92376   15900       77679       44293
    106470  Aug-18  97980   15795       67105       38241
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a step back to first go through some `ggplot2` tutorials. There are 2 major patterns in `ggplot` that are missing in your code: assigning variables to aesthetics, such as color, and the fact that you're accessing columns of your data frame throughout all you `geom_*`s and other functions. Because of that, you don't need `$`, and will actually cause yourself [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543340/5325862) by doing so

Comment: There are several examples in the r-faq tag, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777174/5325862), on reshaping data to get it into the long format that fits `ggplot`'s "grammar of graphics" paradigm. I'd recommend the Tidy Data and Data Visualization chapters of the free [R for Data Science book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

Answer (score 4):

With `ggplot` you need to use a different approach in order to correctly plot.

Refer to [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) to understand better the `grammar`. [Here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/be-awesome-in-ggplot2-a-practical-guide-to-be-highly-effective-r-software-and-data-visualization) another useful guide.

You don't need to call each new line, but instead you call it once, and specify the grouping by the `color` aesthetic.

Note in my code the use of `gather`, in order to get the data in a long format:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) # for the gather function
data %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -dates) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Here the complete code following your example:

```
data %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -dates) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = dates, y = value, color = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(y = value, label=key), hjust = 0, vjust = -0.2) +
  labs(title = "Reli")+
  labs(x="Dates")+
  labs(y="")+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = ""))
```

[image]

Data used:

```
tt <- "expkm actualkm dates  exp      facc        cntrmlg     top10rem
50000 26013   Dec-17  32660   26013       50000       26013
100000 56796   Jan-18  46188   13802       75000       41405
112500 52689   Feb-18  56569   19357       87500       45166
137500 64657   Mar-18  65320   25019       100000      50039
150000 79445   Apr-18  73030   21508       91667       46600
162500 92647   May-18  80000   19592       101786      53178
187500 121944  Jun-18  86410   16473       75000       41183
187500 125909  Jul-18  92376   15900       77679       44293
187500 106470  Aug-18  97980   15795       67105       38241"

data <- read.table(text=tt, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
data$dates <- lubridate::parse_date_time(data$dates, "my") # correct date format
```

Comment: data or data_?? I am getting an error could not find function "gather", I have added dplyr library

Comment: gather() is in library(tidyverse) and library(tidyr). [In RStudio you can type a function name, put the cursor on the name, and press F1 to search for the relevant library.]

Comment: sorry about that, fixed. And it's `data`.

Comment: Great answer.  As a general rule, when you're adding lots of additional geoms for a failry simple graph, you probably need to do more in the `aes()` of the actual `ggplot` call or adjust the underlying data.