# How do you group your data for a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, histogram

I have a dataset of people's birth-year. I want to plot a histogram, but since I am working with a fairly large dataset I would like to group my data in classes of 5. For example, there are 30 people born in the year 1985 but in my histogram I want it to show me that the frequency is 6.

This is the code I have so far for my histogram.

```
ggplot(date, aes(date$year)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = "black") + 
  labs(title = "...", x = "year", y = "frequency")
```

Comment: That does not make sense for a histogram which works with continuous values. Do you mean you want larger bins on a histogram? Or are you plotting a barplot and want bigger intervals?

Comment: [Don't use `$` inside your `aes` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543340/5325862)

Answer (score 3):

You could just change the labels on the y-axis to reflect the transformation you wish:

```
ggplot(date, aes(year)) + 
  geom_histogram(colour = "black") + 
  labs(title = "...", x = "year", y = "frequency") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) x/5)
```

Here's an example with some fake data:

Histogram of the original fake data without transformation:

[image]

Exact same data, with the added `scale_y_continuous` line:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With bar plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dates_df <- data.frame(year = sample(1950:2018, size = 100000,replace = TRUE)) # randomly generated years

classes <- 5  

dates_df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= year, y = cnt/classes)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: @iod solution is what you really need :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
require(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

fake_data <- data.table(name = c('John', 'Peter', 'Alan', 'James', 'Jack', 'Elena', 'Maria'),
                        year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2018))

fake_data %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarize(numb_people = length(unique(name)),
        number_people_freq = length(unique(name))/ 5) %>%
as.data.table() %>%
ggplot(., aes(year)) +
        geom_bar(aes(y = number_people_freq), stat = 'identity') +
        labs(title = "...", x = "year", y = "frequency")]
```

Comment: If you're going with a geom_bar anyway, you don't need to do the transformation in the dataframe. You can just define it inside the aes.