# geom_bar & multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am having trouble getting my plots to work, I have multiple categorical variables by which I want to color by one, and facet by another. However, R keeps adding the "values" (I used melt) for the same variables together instead. It works when I only have one variable.

Here is my plot with one variable
[image: Here is my plot with one variable]

Here is my plot with two variables, you can see the adding that is happening
[image: Here is my plot with two variables, you can see the adding that is happening:]

[simple dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cY5e.png)

Here is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

test2 <- structure(list(SampleID = c(12.19, 12.22, 13.1, 12.19, 12.22, 
13.1, 12.19, 12.22, 13.1, 12.19, 12.22, 13.1), patient = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("L", 
"T"), class = "factor"), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "D", class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 25L, 18L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 15L, 21L, 23L, 
    33L)), .Names = c("SampleID", "patient", "type", "timepoint", 
"Group", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(test2, aes(test2$variable, test2$value, fill=test2$timepoint)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("rosybrown1", "steelblue2", "gray")) +
  labs(x="Category", y="Count", title = paste0("Sample ", as.character(unique(test2$patient)) , " - " , as.character(unique(test2$Group)))) +
  facet_wrap(~test2$type) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=.5, size = 7))
```

Comment: Which variable(s) do you want to colour by?! Also please add sample data using `dput(head(df,12))` rather than images.

Comment: @NelsonGon, i added the structure. I wanted to color by timepoint, and facet by type. However, for this sample, there are timepoints 1 & 2 for type L, and only timepoint 2 for type T

Comment: No need for `$` here: `aes(test2$variable, test2$value, fill=test2$timepoint)`

Comment: wow, that was it? thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the problem as I was still looking at it but that came to mind first.

Comment: I'd go one step further from what @NelsonGon already pointed out: Don't ever use `$` indexing inside `aes`, see [Issue when passing variable with dollar sign notation ($) to aes() in combination with facet_grid() or facet_wrap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio). Concerning the x axis range, are you perhaps after `... + facet_wrap(~ type, scales = "free_x") + ...`?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding right, it looks like you just need to give the scales option to facet_wrap like so:

```
facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free_x")
```