# Making breaks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to define breaks in `ggplot`, but I just get error all the way.

My dataset looks like this: I have 2 rows with `Date` (eks `23.10.2015`) `Number` (eks `43`)

R is not happy with my date format, so I use this command:

```
r$Date_formated <- as.Date(r$Date)(, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

in my script to change the format to this:

```
Date_formated (eks 2015-10-23)
```

This is my whole script

```
r <- read.csv("Date_number.csv", header=T, sep";")
library(tidyverse)
r$Date_formated <- as.Date(r$Date), "%d.%m.%Y")

ggplot(r, aes(r$Date_formated, Number)) +
  ggtitle("Freq") +
  theme_update(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  ylab("Dive") +
  geom_line(aes(group=1), color="blue") +
  labs(title="Freq", x="Time", y="dive") +
  theme_light() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", breaks="1 month", minor_breaks=NULL)
```

I get this error:

> Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument

Does anybody have a good idea to fix this?
I want to have a break for each month in my plot, in the x-axis.

Comment: doesn't it need to be `date_breaks = "1 month"`?

Comment: [Don't use `$` in `aes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio)

Comment: Thank you, symbolrush! That did the trick :-D