# How to add titles to multiple plots of data frames within a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create plots with ggplot for 20 data frames ("df1" - "df20") that are contained in a list called "list1". The list looks like this:

```
list1 <- list(df1, df2, ..., df20)
```

Each data frame has two columns z and y that I want to plot against each other:

```
df1
z  y
1  6
2  9
3  7
```

I have created the following code which also works but it does not provide the plots with the respective titles from df1 to df20:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) 
  ggplot(data = list1$x) + 
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x$z, 
                          y = x$y)))
```

I have tried putting all names in a vector and including this vector in the code like this:

```
titlenames <- c(df1, df2, ..., df20)

+ ggtitle(titlenames)
```

but this only provides the first name for all plot.

Would appreciate any help with this as I am still quite new to R.

Comment: Not related to the title specifically, but [don't put `$` inside your `aes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `mapply` (similar to `lapply` but takes the function first, and can iterate through more than one equal-length list/vector) with the list of data and the vector of names:

```
mapply(function(df, titlename) {
    ggplot(data = df) + 
        geom_line(mapping = aes(x = z, y = y)) +
        ggtitle(titlename)
}, list1, titlenames)
```

I find that because the format of `mapply` differs from `lapply`, it is hard to remember. The package `purrr` provides what I think is a cleaner alternative:

```
purrr::map2(list1, titlenames, function(df, titlename) {
    ggplot(data = df) + 
        geom_line(mapping = aes(x = z, y = y)) +
        ggtitle(titlename)
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The mapply function somehow did not work at first but with the purrr package everything worked smoothly.