# R Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

The plotting code below gives Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I already tried this solution mentioned by stack overflow community but none of them is working. I don't know what wrong with this code.

[Stack Overflow Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278153/plotting-with-ggplot2-error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale-on-c)

[Stack Overflow Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922957/how-to-fix-error-in-r-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale)

What's wrong with this code?

```
#Library Download
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)

#Setting Working Directory
setwd("")
getwd()

#Main Code
data <- read.csv("Test2.csv",header=TRUE)
str(data)
xd <-factor(data$SampleID)
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_bar(data= data,aes(x = xd, y = Average.of.Result,group=Element,color=Element),stat='identity',
  position="dodge",
  na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA,
  fill = rgb(0, 0, 0.8)
)+  
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family ="Segoe UI")+
  geom_line(data=data,aes(x=xd,y=X10xDL,group=Element), size=1.25,color="blue",linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_line(data=data,aes(x=xd,y=Expected.Value,group=Element), size=1.25,color="red",linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family ="Segoe UI")
g
```

Dataset Attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19zD3O9JNx0EqAyFGCZVLRXKjcDnsT_ff/view?usp=sharing)

Any help???

Comment: What is the output of `str(data)`? Are the columns that you are using for `y = ` all coming in as numeric, ie `dbl` or `int`?

Comment: SampleID: Int, Element: chr, Expected.Value: logi,  X10xDL: int, Average.of.Result:num.
This is the result I am getting when I run str(data). I also attached data if you wanted to see actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Your last geom_line uses the logical (aka boolean) values of `Expected.Value` for `y`, while the other `y` variables are numeric. You could replace it with `y = as.numeric(Expected.Value)` for that line, so that TRUE will become 1 and FALSE 0, which can be plotted on a continuous axis.

```
ggplot(data = mutate(mtcars, am_logi = am == 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  # geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = am_logi)) +          # ERROR
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = as.numeric(am_logi)))  # NO ERROR
```