# ggmap and spatial data plotting issue

Tags: r, google-maps, google-api, ggmap

I am trying to update some old code that I inherited from before the Google API days to do a fairly simple (I think) plot.

By the time I get to the plot, my data consists of 50 triplets of latitude, longitude, and $K amount of investment at that location.

```
head(investData)
  amount latitude longitude
1 1404   42.45909 -71.27556
2 1      42.29076 -71.35368
3 25     42.34700 -71.10215
4 1      40.04492 -74.58916
5 15     43.16431 -75.51130
```

at this point I use the following

```
register_google(key = "###myKey###")   #my actual key here

USAmap <- qmap("USA",zoom=4)

USAmap + geom_point(data=investData, aes(x=investData$longitude, y=investData$latitude,size=investData$amount))
```

I've been fighting all ay with establishing accounts and enabling APIs with Google, so it's entirely possible I've simply failed to enable something I need to.  I have the geocoding, geolocation, and maps static APIs enabled.

I get the following output at the console

```
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=USA&zoom=4&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&key=xxx
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=USA&key=xxx
```

But I get no plot.

if I simply run

```
qmap("USA", zoom=4)
```

I get the map I expect.  But when I try to overlay the investment data I get zilch.  I'm told by the folks who handed this to me that it worked in 2017...

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce but try this instead: `print(USAmap + geom_point(data=investData, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,size=amount)))`

Comment: Can't reproduce either. [Don't use `$` inside `aes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio). Beyond that, update packages, restart R, and try again?

Comment: print did it....if you want to make that an answer I'll happily accept it.  And yeah, not sure why the $ were in the aes.  I'll fix that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your script via the source function or with the run command (from inside RStudio) you must explicitly call the `print` function on your ggplot commands.  For example:

```
print(USAmap + geom_point(data=investData, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,size=amount)))
```

As Camille mentioned, no need for the `$` inside the `aes`