# Replicate Excel plot with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a bit of a random ask, but i'm currently going through plotting some data and to get a basic idea I did this within excel to have a quick look.

Now i've managed to get some decent data from [here](https://nwssp.nhs.wales/ourservices/primary-care-services/primary-care-services-documents/gp-practice-analysis-docs/patient-registrations-april-2020) - in Excel I created this plot with a pivot table which *sums* the male count

[image: Male Count by Age & LHB]

But when I try to recreate this within R with ggplot2 i'm stuck.

I *think* i'm just unable to figure out how Excel is **Summing** the MaleCount and unable to replicate in R - This is the plot i'm getting in R without *summing*.

[image]

And this is the code used to create:

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = df$AgeBand, # Axis (Categories)
           y = df$MaleCount)) + # This should be summed somehow.
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(HealthBoard))) + # Legend
  ggtitle("I have no idea")
```

Let me know you have any more questions.
Thanks in advance, Mark.

EDIT: Adding structure below.

```
tibble [50 x 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Period            : num [1:50] 202004 202004 202004 202004 202004 ...
 $ PracticeCode      : chr [1:50] "W96016" "W95001" "W93021" "W91054" ...
 $ PostCode          : chr [1:50] "NP8 1AG" "CF44 7DD" "NP16 5XR" "LL12 7TH" ...
 $ OrgCode           : chr [1:50] "7A7" "7A5" "7A6" "7A1" ...
 $ AgeBand           : num [1:50] 8 24 11 14 68 24 4 56 85 17 ...
 $ MaleCount         : num [1:50] 37 94 49 41 28 53 16 20 4 40 ...
 $ FemaleCount       : num [1:50] 41 98 41 31 28 64 20 14 7 50 ...
 $ IndeterminateCount: num [1:50] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Count             : num [1:50] 78 192 90 72 56 117 36 34 11 90 ...
 $ Year              : num [1:50] 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 ...
 $ Month             : chr [1:50] "April" "April" "April" "April" ...
```

Adding dput below.

```
structure(list(Period = c(202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 
202004, 202004, 202004, 202004, 202004), PracticeCode = c("W95023", 
"W95086", "W91015", "W93045", "W93125", "W97623", "W95073", "W95042", 
"W94017", "W97025", "W95016", "W92048", "W98033", "W94018", "W93116", 
"W93059", "W94035", "W93046", "W92058", "W97016", "W94021", "W98048", 
"W94026", "W97069", "W98012", "W92052", "W93072", "W91044", "W96015", 
"W97060", "W97008", "W94609", "W91038", "W97010", "W92023", "W97067", 
"W93049", "W97028", "W91058", "W97048", "W92023", "W93061", "W91610", 
"W94007", "W95034", "W95024", "W93075", "W95032", "W95087", "W93029"
), PostCode = c("CF48 1BZ", "CF48 3AL", "CH5 3PA", "NP20 6EY", 
"NP18 2JB", "CF5 5LQ", "CF83 3JZ", "CF45 4YB", "LL55 4SU", "CF14 3NB", 
"CF44 6HY", "SA14 8TU", "SA3 5UA", "LL30 3EU", "NP10 8UX", "NP11 6BJ", 
"LL23 7BA", "NP20 4JS", "SA62 6SS", "CF11 9SH", "LL52 0RR", "SA10 6UF", 
"LL65 1RA", "CF3 0SH", "SA4 3ED", "SA15 3BD", "NP25 3PL", "CH7 4RQ", 
"SY16 1EF", "CF24 1AG", "CF23 9PN", "LL54 6NN", "LL22 8LJ", "CF23 8SQ", 
"SA34 0AJ", "CF11 9DG", "NP19 7DQ", "CF14 1LT", "LL13 8RG", "CF24 2HB", 
"SA34 0AJ", "NP10 9DU", "LL12 9LG", "LL36 9HL", "CF33 4LD", "CF37 2DR", 
"NP13 1BQ", "CF46 5HE", "CF44 7AY", "NP44 4TA"), OrgCode = c("7A5", 
"7A5", "7A1", "7A6", "7A6", "7A4", "7A6", "7A5", "7A1", "7A4", 
"7A5", "7A2", "7A3", "7A1", "7A6", "7A6", "7A1", "7A6", "7A2", 
"7A4", "7A1", "7A3", "7A1", "7A4", "7A3", "7A2", "7A6", "7A1", 
"7A7", "7A4", "7A4", "7A1", "7A1", "7A4", "7A2", "7A4", "7A6", 
"7A4", "7A1", "7A4", "7A2", "7A6", "7A1", "7A1", "7A5", "7A5", 
"7A6", "7A5", "7A5", "7A6"), AgeBand = c(87, 31, 44, 53, 23, 
91, 24, 12, 93, 83, 26, 38, 92, 47, NA, 23, 27, 80, 93, 2, 46, 
82, 11, 45, 72, 18, 26, 54, 89, 71, 30, 27, 18, 37, 50, 4, 8, 
51, 59, 8, 4, 64, 92, 13, 88, 85, 78, 56, 45, 44), MaleCount = c(12, 
153, 52, 59, 16, 0, 10, 39, 1, 9, 33, 33, 13, 44, 3, 37, 31, 
15, 0, 17, 18, 8, 39, 24, 143, 84, 24, 23, 6, 30, 129, 21, 61, 
72, 55, 23, 86, 68, 82, 81, 42, 57, 0, 23, 12, 24, 27, 43, 18, 
63), FemaleCount = c(14, 133, 73, 62, 22, 1, 18, 36, 3, 10, 36, 
25, 21, 38, 20, 44, 24, 21, 1, 18, 21, 19, 30, 26, 151, 71, 23, 
17, 27, 20, 132, 17, 65, 70, 55, 28, 73, 73, 69, 80, 28, 74, 
2, 25, 24, 27, 24, 33, 33, 64), IndeterminateCount = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Count = c(26, 286, 125, 121, 38, 1, 28, 75, 
4, 19, 69, 58, 34, 82, 23, 81, 55, 36, 1, 35, 39, 27, 69, 50, 
294, 155, 47, 40, 33, 50, 261, 38, 126, 142, 110, 51, 159, 141, 
151, 161, 70, 131, 2, 48, 36, 51, 51, 76, 51, 127), Year = c(2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), Month = c("April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", "April", 
"April", "April", "April", "April", "April")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: if you add your data structure (via `dput(df)`) we could discuss about it

Comment: The data has 39368 obs of 11 variables - would that be too big to post?

Comment: you could `dput(sample_n(df,200))` to get structure of random 200 samples from your data.

Comment: Error in factor(HealthBoard) : object 'HealthBoard' not found ran your code there is no such thing in your data how did you get the color using that factor?

Comment: Ah yeah - i totally forgot - I changed the OrgCode to HealthBoard (HB) after finding them all.

Comment: [Don't use `$` inside `aes`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543340/5325862)

Comment: @camille, this does actually help! Thanks for this.

Comment: FYI that was a close vote, so if that solves the problem, you can mark it as a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed `OrgCode` to `HealthBoard` according to your comments.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
rename(HealthBoard=OrgCode) %>%
group_by(HealthBoard,AgeBand) %>%
summarise(MaleCount=sum(MaleCount),.groups='drop') %>%
ggplot(aes(x=AgeBand,y=MaleCount,color=HealthBoard))+
geom_line()+
ggtitle('You have some idea now.')
```

**output;**

[image]

Comment: Hey @Samet - I tried with on my _cleaned_ dataset and it looks much closer - I think you were right on it with the summarise part!  

Thank you very much for your time & help.

https://imgur.com/a/nhhiZL9

Comment: @M4rk3h11 you are welcome, consider approving and upvoting the answer if you find satisfying enough.

Comment: I'm still below 15 rep, but i've added that you posted the correct answer for me. :)